# Simple vectorization implementation in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I am new to matlab. Through a simple example I want to understand vectorization. How can I vectorize following code snippet.

```
for i = 1:z
  binno = binno + f*floor(clip(:,:,i)*bins/256);
  f=f*bins;
end
```

It's a really simple code but I do need to understand how I can vectorize it properly.Problem is f is recalculated after each loop.
Edit: Binno is a 2d matrix, Clip is 3d and f and bins are scalar.

Comment: Could you put in some size clarifications? I'm guessing `clip` is 3D,`binno` is a 2D matrix, and `f` and `bins` are scalars?

Comment: @DedekMraz  Yes you are right. I will update the question. Any suggestions as to how do I vectorize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in three steps:

1. create a vector of factors; make it 1-by-1-by-z

   ```
   fact = f .* bins.^(0:z-1);
   fact = reshape(fact,1,1,[]);
   ```
2. multiply clip by factors

   ```
   tmp = bsxfun(@times,floor(clip*bins/256),fact);
   ```
3. sum everything

   ```
   binno = sum(tmp,3);
   ```

Comment: In my original code, if I need to reuse the value of f after the loop ends, i.e final value of f in the loop how do I do it here?

Comment: @Panther: you can use `fact(end)` to use the final value of `f`.

Comment: By any chance is it possible to get different results? Also I want to get value of f as I got in my original loop at the end of original loop.

Comment: @Panther: Oh, I just noticed - the final value of `f` in your original loop is actually `f_final = f*bins^z`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it helps to write down the values of the first few loops, then find the pattern.  The vector F (one entry per iteration) starts at the first `f` (let's call it `f0`).  Then the second entry is `f0*bins`.  Then `f0*bins^2`, etc.  So `F` is `f0*[1 bins bins^2 bins^3]...`
and could be calculated as

```
F = f0 * bins .^ (0:z-1);
```

since bins^0 is 1.

Even before this, you were able compute the entire `floor` operation at once: `floor(clip*bins/256)`.  Now you just need to figure out how to multiply your P-element vector F by that 3D matrix MxNxP.  `bsxfun` will do this sort of thing, but the dimensions need to match, or be exactly 1.  So F must be 1x1xP instead of P.  Then just sum the whole thing along the 3rd dimension.

`binno = sum(bsxfun(@times, floor(clip*bins/256), reshape(F, [1 1 length(F)])), 3);`

Just a note... this question would be more easily answered with your inputs defined at least by size.  Even better is a few lines that generate sample data of the correct dimensions.  Since there is none, I couldn't test the above code, so it's your responsibility to adapt it to your data.